# Pros/cons of placing scripts "inline" in footer or using wp_enqueue_script (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've searched wide and broad but I haven't found any source stating either pros of cons of these two methods, or what the "best" way to enqueue scripts is in Wordpress, with regards to *performance and compatibility*.

So, **my question is the following**:
What are the pros and cons of placing scripts inside a `<script>` in the footer in Wordpress, compared to using `wp_enqueue_script()`?

**My thoughts and example of script**
I'm taking page/load speed very much into consideration and hence I've followed the various "speed optimization" tips of reducing HTTP requests as far as possible. Because of that I've mostly placed scripts "inline" (inside a `<script>`) in the footer, either by using the `wp_footer()` hook or placing them directly in the footer.php file. However, most of my scripts (my own) are small lines of javascript that, however, compile over time. An example of a script can be seen below. I've got many equally-sized codes/scripts as well as some smaller and some larger. It's probably amounting to about 200-300 lines of codes (not minified).

So, with regards to performance I'm kinda guessing that this is preferable, although the impact of having a single HTTP request more for loading the scipt as a file might be completely insignificant. However, this is also where I'm starting to wonder. Would it be better to load this javascript/jquery part from an extra file asynchronously?

Furthermore, another wonder I have is whether it would be better to load the script earlier to avoid any "loss of functionality" compared to loading it as a file? I would rather not load it in the `<head>` as jQuery is required to load first. At the same time it should also be noted that I'm in doubt whether it actually makes a difference, considering that the page load is quite fast nowadays, if optimized.

```
jQuery('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  jQuery('#site-navigation .menu').slideToggle('slow');
  jQuery(function($) {
    if (jQuery('#sitenavigation .menu .children').is(":visible")) {
      jQuery("#sitenavigation .menu .children").slideUp();
    };
  });
});


jQuery(".searchform").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  jQuery(this).parent("div").addClass("selected");
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (jQuery("#search-dropdown-content").hasClass("selected")) {
    jQuery("#search-dropdown").css("color", "#B87E28");
  };
});
```

What's your thoughts on this, and do you have more considerations or pros/cons?

Regards

Comment: you don't want scripts that are used more than once inline, that's a waste. exceptions would be tiny scripts that affecting loading, like a mobile viewport adjuster. scripts linked in the physical html with a <script> will be faster than ones dispatched from another script, because the browser can see the url as soon as the page hits, not after the external script hits.

Comment: @dandavis would you care to explain why it's a waste to have scripts that are used more than once inline? By the way, by "inline" i mean in the footer in case I didnt express that clearly enough (starting to think so when re-reading my post)

Comment: because you're telling the client the same thing over and over, using battery and bandwidth to do so. external js files are cached. you can't cache part of a page. look, 5 years ago, this stuff really mattered. now, just setup for max efficiency and perf will be within 10% of the best you can do anyway.

Comment: So, considering the script above, it's not cached if I place it in a `<script>` inside the footer of my page? So when someone clicks `.searchform` according to the sample script, the browser will have to re-run it all, instead of pulling it from a cache? Didn't know that! I guess that also results in a slower completion time of the script on top of the troubles you described? And does the behaviour you mention only apply to reloading of the page (not cached) or also when running the same script multiple times without reloading the page?

Comment: a footer shows on every page. script text there means each page is heavier as a result. indeed, cached external scripts can be pre-parsed under the hood, while "fresh" script in an "unseen" script tag in a loading page must be re-evaluated. the running perf is the same, it's the loading perf and efficiency that will vary. you can use the devtools to time each permutation, but i suspect that the permutation with the least bandwidth will time very close the one with the least domready time. that was NOT the case a few years back.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for the explanation! I also found these excellent answers to an SO question in the mean time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777253/can-javascript-be-cached-if-it-is-in-the-body-tag-of-an-html-page . This (your comment) actually seems to be a very important consideration which I was missing - thank you! If you want, you could possibly put this as an answer for others to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Firstly, there's of course the option to use wp_enqueue_script and have your scripts printed inline in the footer if you don't mind getting your hands dirty (or find a plugin to do it for you).

As for "which should I do", I'd say it depends, mostly on a) the kind of site you run and b) who your visitors are.

Is it a site where you don't expect many visitors to return (e.g. affiliate landing page), and you don't expect your visitors to have multiple page views ("I need to know this specific information. OK, thanks, bye")? Inline everything.

Is it a site where your users will return regularly, and will hit multiple pages? Then you really want to take advantage of caching static resources, as it will save bandwidth and you will require less server power.

Are your users primarily tech-savvy people on high-bandwidth landlines? You might profit quite a bit from using google's (or other big player's) CDN because they've probably encountered the jquery lib from that CDN before and have it cached.

Are your users primarily mobile, possibly on the move, aka on high-latency, unstable connections? Every back and forth will hurt, performance wise, and inlining will be/feel much quicker.

If you don't outline any js, and have all your js in your footer, you shouldn't experience any lacking functionality, unless you are encountering very specific circumstances (e.g. a mobile user who has been throttled to GPRS and is now crawling along with 10kb/s) in which case whatever you do, nothing will work unless the user waits a long time for everything to complete.

My advise: build both options (hey, it'll also give you new skills), and compare them for the scenarios you envision your users to be in. Use your browser's dev tools, they can usually simulate a slower connection, and might be able to simulate a bad mobile connection. And don't consider it a final decision. As usage patterns change, the other option might become the  better decision, so keep your mind (and an eye) open.

Comment: Excellent considerations! I would like to ask with regards to the "mobile user" consideration though. When the visitor is on a mobile, wouldn't it be preferable to have the scripts cached (loaded in a separate file) rather than inlining them?

Comment: When it's a repeat view (aka they are already cached), totally. When it's the first view, back and forth communication will hurt on (most/bad/slow) mobile connections. This will get better with HTTP2 and server push, but that's quite a way off, and few (actual) servers support it (though most software has the option). So if you have mobile users AND few page views/user = inline. mobile AND lots of page views = outline (though you might want to look into single page apps in that case).

Comment: I understand now. But i guess that if the mobile user "just" visits 2 pages, it would still be a gain to have the javascript cached?

Comment: Possibly, but it would be a small advantage, and my reasoning is primarily: the first page view decides if the user visits your page. Take too long? He's gone. Miss something? He's gone. If he's made it through the door and is interested enough to browse through your items (i.e. viewing another page), he won't mind the (usually small) longer wait (because JS+CSS usually only accounts for a fraction of the data transferred, you might save 40kb but you'll have to load 200kb in images, the 40kb won't even be noticed, really).